# Update Based on Self-Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse

I'm trying to do a simple calculation and update a field based on matching IDs and AsOfDates.  Here is my script.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Vol30Days = 
    (SELECT STDEV(PX_BID) OVER (ORDER BY ID, AsOfDate ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    FROM Prices)
FROM Prices A
    INNER JOIN Prices B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
    AND A.AsOfDate = B.AsOfDate
```

The Subquery works fine and the logic looks ok, but SQL Server is throwing an error, saying FROM clause in UPDATE and DELETE statements cannot contain Subquery sources or joins.

Comment: . . *SQL Server* supports joins in the `FROM` clause.  You need to be more specific about the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a subquery.  I think this is the equivalent logic:

```
UPDATE Prices
    SET Vol30Days = (SELECT STDEV(PX_BID)
                     FROM (SELECT TOP (31) p2.*
                           FROM Prices p2
                           WHERE p2.ID <= prices.ID
                          ) p2
                    );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon!  I just tried it and got this: The multi-part identifier "A.Vol30Days" could not be bound.
I can do this using an intermediate table, but I was looking for something more elegant and easier to maintain, like Tim alluded to.

Comment: @ASH . . . You had that on your previous question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an updatable CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Vol30Days AS VolOrig,
        STDEV(PX_BID) OVER (ORDER BY ID, AsOfDate ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS VolNew
    FROM Prices
)

UPDATE cte
SET VolOrig = VolNew;
```

But given that the new data is just a derived quantity from the same table, you might want to avoid the update, since it might need to be redone any time the table's data changes.  Instead, consider creating a view.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but my version of SQL Server doesn't support CTEs.

Comment: @ASH Then I seriously suggest that you upgrade your version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Use an intermediate storage, like a table variable.

```
DECLARE @BIDS TABLE (ID integer, BIDS numeric(18,2))

INSERT INTO @BIDS (ID, BIDS)
       SELECT A.ID, (SELECT STDEV(PX_BID) OVER (ORDER BY ID, AsOfDate ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) FROM Prices)
       FROM Prices A
            INNER JOIN Prices B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.AsOfDate = B.AsOfDate

UPDATE A SET Vol30Days = B.BIDS
FROM Prices A
     INNER JOIN @BIDS B ON B.ID = A.ID
```

Alternatively you can use a temporal table :

```
SELECT A.ID, (SELECT STDEV(PX_BID) OVER (ORDER BY ID, AsOfDate ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) FROM Prices) AS BIDS
INTO #BIDS 
FROM Prices A
     INNER JOIN Prices B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.AsOfDate = B.AsOfDate

UPDATE A SET Vol30Days = B.BIDS
FROM Prices A
     INNER JOIN #BIDS B ON B.ID = A.ID

DROP TABLE #BIDS
```

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I just tried it and got this: Parse error at line: 1, column: 15: Incorrect syntax near 'TABLE'.

Comment: @ASH It should work. Are you certain that you are using SQL Server ?. What version ?.

Comment: @ASH I have added an alternative using a temporal table

Comment: I'm using Azure Data Warehouse.  It seems to be very, very similar to SQL Server, but I'm seeing some differences as I get deeper and deeper into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Vol30Days = B.Vol30Days
FROM Prices A
    INNER JOIN  (
                    select  t1.ID,
                            t1.AsOfDate,
                            STDEV(PX_BID) OVER (ORDER BY ID, AsOfDate ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)    as  Vol30Days
                    from    Prices t1
                ) B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
    AND A.AsOfDate = B.AsOfDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation on the recommended approach:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#ah-ansi-join-replacement-for-update-statements

- Create a transient table with the results of the JOIN clause
- Write the UPDATE referencing the transient table

Please note that FROM clauses with JOINs - your original strategy - are currently in private preview and will soon move to public preview.

Comment: Thanks Ron.  Thanks everyone.  I'm all set with this thing now!!